# DB2 and JSON, inconsistent quotation of integers

Tags: sql, json, db2, db2-400

I'm using DB2 for i.

The following SQL uses the JSON_ARRAY function in order to produce a json array of three integers.

```
VALUES JSON_ARRAY(1,2,3)
```

Result:

| 00001 |
| --- |
| [1,2,3] |

This seems just right. But when I put it into a function, something changes.

```
CREATE FUNCTION MYSCHEMA.CREATEJSONARRAY01()
RETURNS VARCHAR(512)
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
BEGIN
    RETURN JSON_ARRAY(1,2,3);
END;

VALUES MYSCHEMA.CREATEJSONARRAY01()
```

Here I get:

| 00001 |
| --- |
| ["1","2","3"] |

That is not quite right.

The two examples should produce the same output and first of all I made some tests to see where the problem originates.

Is it the conversion to text?

```
VALUES CAST(JSON_ARRAY(1,2,3) AS VARCHAR(512))
```

This produces the same output of the non-cast version, so the problem does not originate when the entire JSON is converted to string.

I found a solution that is adding FORMAT JSON to each array element.

```
CREATE FUNCTION MYSCHEMA.CREATEJSONARRAY02()
RETURNS VARCHAR(512)
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
BEGIN
    RETURN JSON_ARRAY(1,2 FORMAT JSON,3 FORMAT JSON);
END;
```

| 00001 |
| --- |
| ["1",2,3] |

The reason why it behaves this way however is still unclear to me and that's the main reason of this question.

Comment: Db2 for IBM i does do some implicit conversions when needed.   It would seem to me to be doing so here when not needed.  You could report the bug to IBM.

Comment: I agree, it looks like a bug to me. It happens at v7.2